# some of the UI part is not working on some of the phone browsers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, background, linear-gradients

I have been working on one of my projects(link is given below) using jquery, bootstrap, HTML,CSS. My problem is some of the UI is not working properly in some phone browsers. I am trying to access the website only from google chrome in mobiles. In some of the phones (e.g. chrome version 61) the white background on the home section, icons in the features section, form field colour is showing as white. Please help me to resolve this issue. This site is working perfectly in laptop/desktop via chrome browser.

Website Link: https://dev.prepmaestro.tk/new_landingPage/

```
    <section id="hero-area" >
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="block wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                <!-- Slider -->
                <section class="cd-intro">
                    <h2 class="wow fadeInUp animated cd-headline slide" data-wow-delay=".4s" >

                    <span class="cd-words-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">
                        <b class="is-visible">Is your path to dream career turning into an uphill struggle?</b>
                        <b>Don't worry. Failures are finger posts on the road to achievement</b>

                    </span><br>
                    <span>With the right amount of Preparation & Guidance you can achieve your ambition</span>
                    </h2>
                </section> <!-- cd-intro -->
                    <!-- /.slider -->
                    <h1 class="wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".6s" >
                        Prepare & Practice with PrepMaestro
                    </h1>
                    <a class="btn-lines dark light btn btn-default btn-green" data-wow-delay=".9s" href="#works" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Sign In</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>





 #hero-area {
  background: url("../images/slider.jpg") no-repeat 50%; 
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding: 230px 0;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}

#hero-area:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: 9;
  /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.78);*/
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffffd4, #d4d4d49c); /* the standard */
```

Comment: Please include the code required to repro the issue in the question itself.

Comment: @ZimSystem, please click on the link provided from your mobile. You will get the issue.

Comment: @ZimSystem Codes added for the background issue.